# Bound for $(ax+b)e^{-cx^2-dx}$

Tags: calculus, optimization, exponential-function, approximation, upper-lower-bounds

For positive constants $a,b,c,d$, I'm interested in an upper bound for $g(x)=(ax+b)e^{-cx^2-dx}$ for $x\geq 0$ in terms of the constants.

One approach is just to solve the maximization problem $\max_{x\geq 0}g(x)$, but it cannot be done in closed form (I think).

A simple approach is to bound $ax+b\leq e^{ax+b-1}$, which yields an upper bound for $g$ that can be maximized.
I just need one "good" bound for $g(x)$ and this feels like an studied problem, any reference will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the classic method of finding points where the derivative is 0. Those are going to be local extrema of your function. Then, a quick study of the sign of the derivative will lead you to finding the exact global maximum.

Take your function $g : x \mapsto (ax + b)e^{-cx^2 - dx}$ and derivate it. It gives :

$g'(x) = (a + (ax + b)(-2cx - d))e^{-cx^2 - dx} \\ = (a - bd - 2bcx - adx - 2acx^2)e^{-cx^2 - dx}$

Can you take it from there ?

Comment: I made a mistake with the derivative and my exponentials didn't cancel, duh. Thanks